# Eureka Client: Eureka Registry server address alternative to 'localhost'

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

Eureka-server(MediaStoreEurekaServer): bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=MediaStoreEurekaServer
server.port=9091
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9091/eureka}
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Eureka-client(Config-Server): bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=Config-Server
server.port=9093
user.home=${HOME}
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file://${user.home}/IdeaProjects/MediaStore/centralProperties
spring.profiles.active=native
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:9091/eureka
```

With above 2 properties (**services running on same machine**), **Config-Server** is able to register with **MediaStoreEurekaServer** eureka registry server when using **http://localhost:9091/eureka**.

I don't want to use **localhost**. When I use http://**MediaStoreEurekaServer**:9091/eureka , Config-Server is not able to register.

## Can we use something other than **localhost** for eureka client to find the eureka server like service or instance name? when services are running on same host

### Edit 1:

This is what eureka client spring logs give when in eureka client properties file i set
`eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://MediaStoreEurekaServer:9091/eureka`
Error:

````
2020-05-22 20:01:02.137 ERROR 22846 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://MediaStoreEurekaServer:9091/eureka/}

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: MediaStoreEurekaServer```
````

Comment: Yes you can. Do you have an error you can share?

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for replying. I added the error log under EDIT 1. Please have a look.

Comment: It seems that the `MediaStoreEurekaServer` is not a valid hostname/address. Eureka client `service-url` registration doesn't use the application name to auto-discover the server.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero
So does that mean that there is no alternative to 'localhost' in `service-url` for discovery of eureka server (standalone, single) by eureka clients on the same host?

Comment: MediaStoreEurekaServer isn't a resolvable host name. You need the real host name or ip address

Comment: As Spencer said, you need a resolvable hostname, it can be an IP, a hostname configured on your instance, a domain. 
Using the application name won't work because it can't be resolved.